# Find matching values in Excel columns

Tags: excel

i currently have the following excel columns

```
2014 2015 2016
1    2    1 
4    12   4
8    17   6
```

I would like to find a way of pulling out the values in the column of 2016 that are NOT in 2014 and not in 2015 columns

so for example the value 6 in 2016 is not in the column 2014 nor is it in the column 2015, I would like a formula which would pull this value out, or do something like have "not match" for the values which are repeated and the actual value like 6 if it is unique to the 2016 column and not 2014 or 2015

I know this has to be super simple, but i am so stuck on which excel forumla to write

Any help is great!

Comment: Assuming these are columns `A`, `B`, and `C` and the data starts on `A2`, then in `D2` `=Countif(A:B, C2)>0` will return `True` or `False` if the value in `C2` is present in the `A` or `B` column. Copy that down to get a list of `True/False` that you can filter on.

Comment: I need the actual numbers returned, not true or false so i would like the number 6 returned

Comment: what if there are more than one number that is not found, is the returned a list in multiple cells or a concatenated string in  a single cell?

Comment: Does order matter?  If so, what order, as it appears,ascending,descending?  All have different methods.

Comment: just want a column next to it, which would return the value if it is unique and does not appear in the other columns, and if it does appear in the other columns then it would return something like "bad" or nothing at all

Comment: why downvote the question

Comment: You can just put that countif in an `if`...  `=If(Countif(A:B, C2)>0, C2, "")`.

Comment: Probably downvoted because this is the most basic of excel functionality and it shows VERY little research effort before asking. I didn't downvote though, so I'm just guessing here.

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula in your output.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:B2,C2)>=1,C2,"N/A") //This will pull out matching.
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:B2,C2)>=1,"N/A",C2) //This will pull out non-matching.
```

*Thanks to @Scott for the false positive details.

[image]

Comment: One moment, will fix this I see that you're looking for "NOT"

Comment: =IF(COUNTIF(A2:B2,C2)=1,C2,"N/A") will only pull out if a single match occurs. =IF(COUNTIF(A2:B2,C2)=1,"N/A",C2) will produce C2 if A2=B2=C2

Comment: @FocusWiz it will pull out if a double match occurs. Changed "=" to ">=".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:B,C2)=0,C2,"not match"))
```

which you would put in Cell D2 to evaluate Cell C2 and then copy to as many other rows need similar evaluation?

If not, what kind of formulas gave you results that you do not like in addition to this alternative?

As an aside, I find reporting "not match" for items which match to be a confusing narrative to use.

Per the comments, I have adjusted this to search all values in Columns A and B for a match, not just the current row.  Thus, in the image below, the 792 in C6 is found in column A26 and the 279 in C10 appears in A11.  None of the other 2016 values appear in either column A nor B.

[image]

Another alternative if don't mind code that is a bit unreadable might be:

```
=CHOOSE(INDEX(SMALL(1*(C2<>A:B),1),1)+1,"not match",C2)
```

but if you don't care about the "not match" verbiage and can handle a zero instead, I like this:

```
=INDEX(SMALL(C2*(C2<>A:B),1),1)
```

Comment: I believe that OP wants to find that the value in `C2` doesn't exist ANYWHERE in columns A and B, not just in the same row.

Comment: This compares row by row and as such would return all three entries.  This is not what the OP wants

Comment: Thanks.  Will  change accordingly.